# Dispose frame after start frame Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm new to Stackoverflow. I have a problem in java/swing with project to school.

The project is a testing service. I want to run an additional window before running the main program that checks the connection to the server. After checking the connection it should start the main window of the program and disappear. If I manually click `startProgramButton` it's all right. However, if the program is connected to the server at startup, the main window of the program is started, but this window does not disappear.

```
public class PreForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form PreForm
 */
MainForm form1;
Settings form2;

public PreForm() {
    initComponents();
    checkConnection();
}



private void settingsButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    errorLabel.setText("");
    form2 = new Settings();
    form2.setVisible(true);
}                                              

private void runProgramButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    checkConnection();
}                                                

private void checkConnection() {
    if (hostAvailabilityCheck()) {
        runMainProgram();
    } else
        errorLabel.setText("<html>Error connect to server!<br>"
                + "Check connect settings and try again!</html>");
}
private boolean hostAvailabilityCheck() {
    try (Socket s = new Socket(SettingsFile.getAddress(), Integer.parseInt(SettingsFile.getPort()))) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        /* ignore */
    }
    return false;
}

private void runMainProgram() {
    this.setVisible(false);
    form1 = new MainForm();

    form1.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new PreForm().setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}
```

So, after running the program, the `checkConnection` method is executed. Then the `runMainProgram` method is executed. And that's where `this.setVisible (false)` code comes in, which should hide the window, but it stays. But only if the `checkConnection` method is started in the constructor. If you run it manually through the `startProgramButton`, this window is hidden.

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) Don't add irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with the IDE.